# How to add a star rating in custom form in magento 2

Tags: forms, magento2.2.2, ratings

I have created the **feedback** form in list page. Now I wish to add **custom star rating** as a new form field.

Please suggest any solution to add rating field in my form.

Comment: Did you get a solution ?